# Как передать структуру по сети?

Tags: c++, qt, сериализация

Возникла проблема с передачей структуры типа ниже, да и вообще с любыми структурами. С другими типами все хорошо: `QStringList`, `QImage`, `QString`, без проблем, сервер передаёт, а клиент получает их.
Есть ли варианты как передать структуру наиболее разумным способом?

```
struct CommandStruct
{
  uint id;
  QString text_cmd;
  QString text_btn;

  CommandStruct(uint _id, QString _text_cmd, QString _text_btn) {
   id = _id;
   text_cmd = _text_cmd;
   text_btn = _text_btn;
 }

 CommandStruct(){}

 };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для этого нужно переопределить 2 оператора для Вашей структуры:

```
QDataStream & operator<< (QDataStream& stream, const CommandStruct& command);
QDataStream & operator>> (QDataStream& stream, CommandStruct& command);
```

Для Q* классов у Вас всё работает, потому что для каждого из них есть такая перегрузка с [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html)

Comment: Благодарю, буду делать.

Answer (score 3):

Для передачи произвольных данных нужно определиться с протоколом прикладного уровня - то есть с форматом, в котором ваша структура будет храниться в пакете. Есть случаи, когда можно использовать свои протоколы, а есть и такие, когда можно использовать готовые. Среди готовых можно выделить формат JSON, и в Qt есть [специальные классы](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html) для работы с этим форматом. В этом формате можно передавать данные абсолютно любой структуры, размерности и типа.

В случае, если объём передаваемых данных критичен, лучше сделать свой протокол, специально приспособленный для вашей задачи. Но у этого подхода есть серьёзный минус - созданное решение будет очень тяжело масштабировать, например, если понадобится передавать ещё какие-то данные помимо вашей структуры. В вашем случае решение может быть, например таким: 4 байта - идентификатор, 4 байта - длина первой строки, первая строка переменной длины, 4 байта - длина второй строки, вторая строка. Примерная реализация:

```
QByteArray packet;
QBuffer packBuffer(packet);
QDataStream packStream(packBuffer);
packStream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);
packStream << id;
packStream << text_cmd.size();
packStream.writeBytes(text_cmd.toLatin1().data(), text_cmd.size());
```

Чтобы каждый раз не писать все поля структуры в пакет, можно, как уже заметил @ixSci, перезагрузить оператор `<<` у вашей структуры.

Comment: Благодарю, буду делать.